# Implement copy constructor with bridge pattern c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, constructor, bridge

I'm studying c++ and trying to implement the bridge pattern, when this happens, I have My implementation file with constructors:

```
 SystemImpl::SystemImpl() {
    this->name = "";
    this->value = 0.0;
    this->maxValue = DBL_MAX;
}

SystemImpl::SystemImpl(const SystemImpl& sys) {
    this->name = sys.name;
    this->value = sys.value;
    this->maxValue = sys.maxValue;
}
```

And now, I'm creating the interface that use this implementation, where imps is my pointer to implementation class:

```
System::System() {
    imps = new SystemImpl();
}

System::System(const System& sys) {
    imps = new SystemImpl(sys);
}
```

The fisrt constructor work's fine, but the second, that's a copy constructor, shows 
**no matching function for call to ‘SystemImpl::SystemImpl(const System&)’**

What's wrong?

Comment: SystemImpl is the implementation for System, I use the implementation in the interface, not reverse, i guess

Comment: This seems like a case of "just read the error message"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `imps = new SystemImpl(sys);`, the compiler complains that `SystemImpl` doesn't have a constructor taking `System` as its parameter.

You might want

```
System::System(const System& sys) {
    imps = new SystemImpl(*sys.imps);
}
```